# Where does abort() and terminate() "live"?

Tags: c++

Regarding the terminate handler,

As i understand it, when something bad happens in code, for example when we dont catch an exception,

terminate() is called, which in turn calls abort()

set_terminate(my_function) allows us to get terminate() to call a user specified function my_terminate.

my question is: where do these functions "live" they don't seem to be a part of the language, but work as if they are present in every single cpp file, without having to include any header file.

Comment: You have to include headers for the function that _you_ call. Therefore, your statement "without having to include any header file" doesn't apply to `set_terminate()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there are default handler functions for `terminate` and `abort` that you did not install yourself, they'd have to be in the runtime library provided by your compiler.

Normally, every program is linked against the runtime library (e.g. `glibc` under Linux). Among other reasons, this is because the runtime library contains "hidden" code for essential things, e.g. code that calls your `main` function at startup.

Comment: Thanks stakx, the presence of a runtime library explains things.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you think there is no need to include a header:

```
int main() {
    abort();
}
```

gives the following error for me:

```
error: 'abort' was not declared in this scope
```

Neither C nor C++ have any "special" functions - if you want to use a function, you must declare it somehow. These two live in the C++ Standard Library, and are declared in `cstdlib` and `exception`. Of course, these headers themselves may be #included by other headers, thus making the functions available, but this is not specified by the standard.

Comment: @Neil: I think he's referring to the fact that the default unexpected function calls terminate(), yet the user is not required to #include a header that contains terminate() in order for that to work.

Answer (score 2):

[set_terminate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/set_terminate/) - terminate handler function

Sets f as the terminate handler function.

A terminate handler function is a function automatically called when the exception handling process has to be abandoned for some reason. This happens when a handler cannot be found for a thrown exception, or for some other exceptional circumstance that makes impossible to continue the handling process.

The terminate handler by default calls [cstdlib's abort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abort/) function